# Prove that there is a number such that elements of a vector space are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

I am inexperienced with math and linear algebra and need help with the following question.

Let $v, w$ be elements of a vector space and assume that $v\neq0$. If $v, w$ are linearly
dependent, show that there is a number $a$ such that $w = av$.

My professor said that to prove $w=av$ I need to prove an existence of $a$. How do I do that?

I know that if vectors $x,y$ are linearly dependent then there are scalars $c,d\in\mathbb{F}$, not all zero, such that $cx+dy=0$. $($Where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.$)$

Comment: You are using the letter $a$ for multiple things here.  I'll rewrite the earlier statement.  $v,w$ linearly dependent shows that there are scalars $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1v+c_2w = 0$.  Now, can you solve for $w$ in this?

Comment: $w=-\frac abv $ exists because nonzero field elements have a multiplicative inverse

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, we can find $a,b\in \Bbb{F}$ not both zero so that $av+bw=0$. Suppose that $a\ne 0$, then $av=-bw$ and hence dividing we get $v=-\frac{b}{a}w$. The case of $b\ne 0$ is analogous.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$av+bw=0 \Rightarrow av=-bw \Rightarrow a^{-1}av=a^{-1}(-b)w \Rightarrow v=a^{-1}(-b)w$

Note i've used some properties of fields here (which one?)

Comment: If $a$ exists then it has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}$. How does rearranging $w=av$ to $v=a^{-1}w$ prove that $a$ exists? Because $v\neq0$, then $a$ is at least 1?