# Proof verification: two elements of a vector space are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am inexperienced with math and need verification of my answer to the following question:

Let $v,w$ be elements of a vector space and assume that $v\neq0$. If $v,w$ are linearly dependent, show that there is a number $a$ such that $w=av$.

My answer/proof:

$w=av \implies v=a^{-1}w$. Since $v\neq0$ this implies that $w\neq0$ and $a^{-1}\neq0$, which implies that $a$ exists because $a\in\ \mathbb{F}$ has a multiplicative inverse $a^{-1}\in\mathbb{F}$. $($Where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.$)$

Am I missing anything?

Comment: It's literally the definition " a set of vectors is said to be linearly dependent if at least one of the vectors in the set can be defined as a linear combination of the others". Nothing to prove. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition

Comment: I know I saw this question yesterday, but it appears to have been deleted.  In any case, you haven't properly stated or used the definition of linear dependence.  $v,w$ are linearly dependent means that there exist constants $c_1,c_2$ such that $c_1v+c_2w=0$.  The point is to try to rearrange this as $w = av$ where $a$ is some constant (*which you will find will be related to $c_1,c_2$*)

Comment: As for your attempt... you started with what you wanted to prove and worked from there... This is not how you should be structuring your proofs.  You should start with your hypotheses and show that these imply what you want to show.  $w=av$ should have been your *conclusion*

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999741/prove-that-there-is-a-number-such-that-elements-of-a-vector-space-are-linearly-d

Comment: @Raffaele My professor said that I need to prove an existence of $a$.

Comment: Yes... and as alluded to already here and in your previous attempt at asking this, given $c_1v+c_2w=0$ with at least one of which is nonzero, you will have by rearranging $c_1v=-c_2w$ and assuming $c_1\neq 0$ you have $v = \frac{-c_2}{c_1}w$.  "*Proving the existence of $a$*" is done by saying "*Hey, look... if $a=\frac{-c_2}{c_1}$ then we do in fact have $v = aw$.*"  The only missing details is in taking care of the case of zeroes appearing.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I attempted to delete the original post because I misused symbols and it became too confusing, and the post wasn't getting any more attention. And yes, I don't quite know how to structure a proof yet.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ok thank you very much. To take care of the case of zeroes appearing, is stating the following sufficient? "$v\neq0 \implies a\neq0$ and $w\neq0$"

Answer (score 1):

Linear dependence of $v,w$ means that there exist scalars $a,b$ NOT both zero such that

$av+bw=0$.

Suppose $a\ne 0$. Then $v=(-b/a)w$ as claimed. Both vectors are collinear.

Suppose $a=0$. Then $bw=0$ and so $w=0$.

Comment: Linear dependence means there exist scalars $a,b$ not both zero...

Comment: @Wuestenfux In your last statement you are saying that $a=0$ and $w=0$ is not possible because $v\neq0$?

Comment: I just the case distinction $a=0$ and $a\ne 0$.